# cplex from MATLAB using parfor

Tags: matlab, cplex, parfor

I have a fairly large scale optimization problem although the problem itself is fairly simple. It is just quadratic + linear objective, with linear constraints. So the problem is solvable with cplexqp. The scale of the problem is around 1300 variables, but I need to solve ~200 independent problems.

If I just loop over 200 times and call cplexqp as usual, it takes about 16 minutes to solve all the problems. I considered using parallel computing, so I changed the loop to parfor, and it now takes around 14 minutes. I would have thought we would get much bigger speedup factor, considering that we have 12 cores and 12 workers.

I made sure that the parallel worker is already initialized (so MATLAB does not have to spend time initializing them). I also verified that all 12 worker threads were active in task manager, and they all were using non trivial amount of CPU each.

My question is: do you think cplexqp has a locking mechanism, as in it can't be called with more than one problem at a given time (from different threads?) What if I have different MATLAB processes? (For example I can save the inputs to a file, and start up several MATLAB sessions to consume the file and each session would know which index of problems to solve).

16 minutes is not bad, but we may need to do this several times a day (with potentially different inputs), so I was wondering if we can speed up the process even more.

TIA

Comment: How was your CPU utilization to start with (not using parfor)? I guess cplex already uses multiple cores, not leaving much room for improvement.

Comment: That's a good point. Turns out it has been using a lot of the cores(~60 pct utilization). This makes sense given that the algorithm needs to process many rows of the tableau and they're all "independent" operations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by default CPLEX will use *all* cores on your machine to solve *one* problem. So if you attempt to solve multiple problems in parallel then you are heavily oversubscribing the CPUs. This is likely to result in an overall slowdown.

So you should carefully select how many models you solve in parallel and how many cores you allow for each solve. If you use `parfor` then you should use the [Cplex.Param.threads](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/Threads.html) parameter to limit he number of cores for a single solve, or alternatively, select the simplex algorithm to solve your QPs.

Whether this whole parallelization gives you an overall speedup depends on how much slowdown you will observe for the individual models by limiting the thread counts.